# What opening variation begins with c4?

Tags: opening

Black’s best response to White’s c4 opening move; what is the name of this opening?

Comment: There is no one "best" response to 1.c4. If there were, all the others would be dismissed

Comment: FWIW, stockfish likes e6 against c4. And see https://www.chess.com/article/view/english-opening-chess

Comment: If you do a Google search with the exact title of your question, the Wikipedia article on the English Opening is one of the very first hits. This leads me to suspect that you didn't attempt any research before asking the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is called the English Opening.  The objective of the opening is to apply pressure on the center d5 square without committing the queen pawn or the king pawn.  The standard response is 1..., e5 (Reversed Sicilian), but there are many other options, 1..., c5 for example (Symmetrical) or 1..., e6, a more manuevering type of game.  This opening is known for its transpositional possibilities.  For example it often ends up as some form of Queen's Pawn Opening.  It is favored by many players because of this non-committal nature.